# Intuition behind why $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

We learned in my linear algebra course last semester that two vectors spaces $U$ and $V$ over some field $F$ are said to be ${\it isomorphic}$ if there exists a bijection (invertible linear map) between them.

Consider the vector spaces $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. If we consider $\mathbb{C}$ as

$$
\mathbb{C} = \left\{ a + bi \ | \ a, b \in \mathbb{R} \right\},
$$

then it seems that $\mathbb{C}$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. That is, we can define the following map $\phi: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^2$:

$$
\phi(a + bi) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a \\ b \end{array}\right)
$$

which is clearly invertible and therefore a bijection between the two. However, it seems weird that $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ just based on intuition. Can anyone give me a better way to think about this isomorphism?

Comment: The title is misleading.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar How so?

Comment: @TrevorWilson The title says "intution", whereas the body says "it seems weird that $\mathbb C\cong\mathbb R^2$ just based on intuition".

Comment: I've always found it perfectly intuitive to think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the plain old Cartesian $x,y$ plane. The complex plane just renames the axes as "real vs. imaginary" instead of "$x$ vs. $y$."

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I took that to mean "just based on intuition, it seems weird that $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$," which would fit with the title.

Comment: It might be easier to answer this question if you say something about your intuition for $\mathbb{C}$ and where it comes from.

Comment: I agree with @MaliceVidrine; it's not clear to me what you find unintuitive. If you view $\mathbb{C}$ using the Argand diagram (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane), then you are already identifying points of $\mathbb{C}$ with points of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: As an idea of where OP might be coming from: it's important to note that $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic *as vector spaces over* $\mathbb{R}$.  Certainly, in our typical discussion of $\mathbb{C}$, we allow multiplication by complex scalars, which is a level of structure not inherent to $\mathbb{R}^2$. If we restrict ourselves to real scalars, however, then $\mathbb{C}$ is simply a fancy version of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @kelsy I don't know what you mean. This doesn't seem to be based on intuition at all. It seems to be based upon a concrete map you gave and / or the definition of the complex numbers you learned.

Comment: If $\Bbb C\cong\Bbb R^2$ seems weird based on intuition, then you haven't worked with complex numbers very much. Do you know that every complex number can be expressed uniquely as an $\Bbb R$-linear combination of $1$ and $i$? Is this intuitive?

Answer (score 4):

We build the complex numbers $\mathbb C$ by taking the real numbers $\mathbb R$ and adding on the imaginary unit $i$, satisfying $i^2=-1$. But as a vector space, $\mathbb C$ has no multiplicative structure; after all, the vector space axioms say nothing about multiplying vectors, only about adding them.
It no longer matters that $i^2=-1$ because we don't know how to multiply two vectors in $\mathbb C$. In that sense $i$ is an arbitrary placeholder -- we could just as well call it $x$, for example, and talk about the vector space of polynomials of the form $a+bx$.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst in some sense you are right, the intuition is not correct.

I mean, it is correct if you think of them both as two real vector spaces; $$\mathbb{R}^2 = span\left\{\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right) \right\},\quad C =span\left\{(1+0i),(0+1i) \right\} $$
then there is indeed an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $C$ as you described.

The key difference is that $\mathbb{C}$ is a (algebraic) field, so we think of $\mathbb{C}$ as a set of points ($C$ as described above, and thus isomorphic to the euclidian plane), with two closed operators $(+,\cdot)$ which map $C\times C \rightarrow C$.

Now the intuition holds up when we think about the addition operator. Adding vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equivalent to adding complex numbers. We also have in both, an additive identity and additive inverses.

The key difference is multiplication. A vector space doesn't come with a closed multiplication operator. For instance, the scalar product, which is what comes to mind when we think about multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^2$ doesn't even map back into $\mathbb{R}^2$!

For $\mathbb{C}$ however, if we multiply two complex numbers, we will get a complex number out the other end. I.e. it's closed. (and also has identities, inverses, commutativity and distributive properties.)

In short, 
$\mathbb{C}$ is a field and as such has a whole bunch more structure than $\mathbb{R}^2$.
The intiution is fine as long as you're only thinking about the points, and not operations on those points.